# SML programming to racket programming

Tags: racket

Using SML, I have completed a problem called dates_in_month that takes a list of dates and a month (i.e., an int) and returns a list holding the dates from the argument list of dates that are in the month. While it's done and easy in SML, my question is how this would I write the same program in the Racket programming language, where functions and lists are defined and used differently?

An example is (dates_in_month 5 [(2002 05 12) (1999 05 12) (1980 12 20)]), and the output should be (2002 05 12) (1999 05 12) because those are the dates where the months is 5.

Comment: Please provide some examples of expected input and output (how do you represent dates?) and code you have already tried.

Comment: You might include how you did it in sml too.

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively straightforward with `filter`:

```lisp
(define (dates_in_month n l)
  (filter (lambda (date) (= (cadr date) n)) l))
```

then

```lisp
> (dates_in_month 5 '[(2002 5 12) (1999 5 12) (1980 12 20)])
'((2002 5 12) (1999 5 12))
>
```

Comment: Using `eq?` to compare numbers is a bad habit. Works in this case because you're comparing fixnums, but it'll fail with other number types. `eqv?` or `=` is more reliable.

Comment: @Shawn edited accordingly, I always mess up the equality operators.